# Rake tasks inside telegram bot gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, telegram-bot, rake-task

I have this telegrambot.rb file

```
require 'telegram/bot'
require 'rake'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")
Myapp::Application.load_tasks
token = "mytoken"
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
    bot.listen do |message|
        case message.text
        when "Try"
            pp "before task"
            Rake::Task["alpha:try"].invoke
            pp "after task"
        end
    end
end
```

Then in my tasks I have this task which just touches a product in the db:

```
namespace :alpha
    task try: :environment do
        pp "in the task"
        prod = BaseProduct.first
        prod.touch(:updated_at)
    end
end
```

Now if I send the message everything works as expected and I get 
"before task"
"in the task"
"after task"
Also,if I checkthe db the product has been touched.
But, if I send the message over again, I get this result
"before task"
"after task"
And of course the product has not been touched.
Also, no error gets raised, as if the instruction that launches the task got bypassed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in rake's invoke method which only calls the task once. 
Adding a reenable to the task after the execution solved the issue.